# An exception occurred while running exporter #2:hbm2ddl (Generates database schema)

Tags: hibernate, gradle, ant, schema, hibernate-tools

I'm try to generate dbSchema with the following task launch (eclipse whith maven project)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.buildship.core.launch.runconfiguration">
<listAttribute key="arguments"/>
<stringAttribute key="gradle_distribution" value="GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION(WRAPPER)"/>
<listAttribute key="jvm_arguments"/>
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.ui.favoriteGroups">
<listEntry value="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchGroup.run"/>
</listAttribute>
<booleanAttribute key="show_console_view" value="true"/>
<booleanAttribute key="show_execution_view" value="false"/>
<listAttribute key="tasks">
<listEntry value="dbSchema"/>
</listAttribute>
<booleanAttribute key="use_gradle_distribution_from_import" value="false"/>
<stringAttribute key="working_dir" value="${workspace_loc:/MyProject}"/>
</launchConfiguration>
```

And this is the error from the console log:

```html
[ant:hibernatetool] An exception occurred while running exporter #2:hbm2ddl (Generates database schema)
[ant:hibernatetool] To get the full stack trace run ant with -verbose
[ant:hibernatetool] javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: yadaPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
[ant:hibernatetool] java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '%'
```

What is this error generated from?

```
[ant:hibernatetool] java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '%'
```

How to solve this problem? Is a problem generated by the entity?

The task has always worked correctly so far, and I have not made any changes. What can it depend on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by this line in the Settings class:

```
LOG.debugf("Using BatchFetchStyle : %", sessionFactoryOptions.getBatchFetchStyle().name());
```

It should be "%s", not "%":

```
LOG.debugf("Using BatchFetchStyle : %s", sessionFactoryOptions.getBatchFetchStyle().name());
```

Looks like [this commit](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/6b489474f58033fe9b52e1c5c866b421c8c4f3e2) has added the issue. Most likely, the issue was not detected because the log level is not set to debug.

Try setting it to debug:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cfg=debug
```

Answer (score 1):

Want to add to **peppe**'s answer: there are new versions, where this issue has been fixed. I've upgraded to `5.4.9.Final`, and it's working fine.